# División de enteros para obtener múltiplos de un número en OpenCL

Tags: números-enteros, division, opencl

En mi algoritmo necesito determinar si un número es múltiplo o no de otro, si el número es múltiplo, la división me devuelve el entero múltiplo y si no, me devuelve cero. Un ejemplo:

```
int block_y;
int reps  = 2;
int index = (256 * block_y) + (64 * (block_y / reps));
// block_y runs from 0 to 10 for example.
//   - if block_y = 1 -> (block_y / reps) = 0
//   - if block_y = 2 -> (block_y / reps) = 1
//   - if block_y = 3 -> (block_y / reps) = 0
//   - if block_y = 4 -> (block_y / reps) = 2
```

¿Existe alguna función especifica en OpenCL para hacer esto? he buscado en la documentación de *khronos* para *OpenCL* y no he visto ninguna función específica para hacer esto.
En el caso de que no exista ninguna función específica, ¿es correcto realizarlo así? ¿es esta la forma mas óptima en referencia a tiempo de computación y Nº de ciclos necesarios para la operación?

Comment: Puedes hacer un condicional simple de acuerdo al módulo arrojado, la función incorporada que arroja el módulo es `fmod`.